# При компиляции выдает такую ошибку " describe_battery() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' ".Как исправить?

Tags: python

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        self.make=make
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
        self.odometer_reading=0 
    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name=str(self.year)+" "+self.make+" "+self.model
        return long_name.title()
    def read_odometer(self):
        print("This car has "+str(self.odometer_reading)+" miles on it.")
    def update_odometer(self,mileage):
        self.odometer_reading=mileage
        if mileage>=self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading=mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")
    def increment_odometer(self,miles):
        self.odometer_reading+=miles
class Battery():
    def __init__(self,battery_size=70):
        self.battery_size=battery_size
    def describe_battery(self):
        print("This car has a "+str(self.battery_size)+" kWh battery.")
    def get_range(self):
        if self.battery_size==70:
            range=240
        elif self.battery_size==85:
            range=270
    message="This car can go aproximately "+str(range)
    message+=" miles on a full charge."
    print(message)
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        super().__init__(make,model,year)
        self.battery=Battery
my_tesla=ElectricCar("tesla","model s",2016)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас поле инициализируется классом, а не объектом

```
self.battery = Battery()
```